# std::thread causes SIGABRT in android JNI

Tags: android, c++, multithreading

I'm trying to create a simple `std:thread` from `jni` in `android`. But my application crash with the following error.

```
A/libc: Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT) at 0x00005606 (code=-6), thread 22059
```

JNI source:

```
void threadRun(){
    sleep(5);
}

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_com_helloworld_JNIWrapper_init
  (JNIEnv *env, jobject obj)
{
     thread th(threadRun);
     th.join(); //or th.detach() doesn't work either
}
```

Application.mk:

```
APP_STL := gnustl_static
APP_CPPFLAGS += -std=c++11
```

I called `init` method from Activity in main UI thread. From background thread it didn't work either.

Answer (score 2):

Well, it seems it is a "well known, not publicized" bug in clang, not yet fixed in the current NDK version (at time of writing, r10d for me).

The solution seems to compile using g++ instead. To do this, simply add the following lines to your gradle script:

```
externalNativeBuild {
    cmake {
            arguments "-DANDROID_TOOLCHAIN=gcc"
    }
}
```

Some link:

- https://bugs.llvm.org//show_bug.cgi?id=23428
- https://github.com/OlehKulykov/FayeCpp/issues/2

Hope that helps... (I spent a lot of hours on that, doh!)